# Larave 6 - pivot table sync - fire created event only if the attached user is new

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have following code:

```
$clinic->users()->sync($sync);
```

Which will go to this class (sync is working):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class ClinicUser extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'clinic_user';

    static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::created(function($item) {

            $user   = \App\User::find($item->users_id);
            $clinic = \App\Models\Clinic::find($item->clinics_id);

            if($user->userData->notification_email == 1)
                \Mail::to($user->email)->send(new \App\Mail\ClinicManagerAdded(
                    $user,
                    $clinic));

            if($user->userData->notification_app == 1)
                \App\Notification::create([
                    'title'   => "message",
                    'body'    => "message",
                    'user_id' => $user->id,
                ]);

        });
    }
}
```

Is it possible to fire created method only to the new users (does which weren't detached)?

Comment: maybe using `syncWithoutDetaching()`?

Comment: Well I need to send the notification and email to the newly attached users, and remove those aren't selected (this action if fired on the update, so it is possible that the set of users is completely changed).

Comment: so you have a clinic with some users, then you have other users (inside $users), and you want to remove from the associated users the once that are not inside $users, and then send a notification to the once that are new? i'm thinking about something like `->detach($users); -> syncWithoutDetaching ($users)`

Comment: Found a way - I have created a static variable for the class and fill it on deleted event :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i was suggesting is not that robust, infact you need to do

```
$clinic->users()->detach($sync->pluck('id'));
$clinic->users()->sync($sync);
```

Every time, and you need to remember it (and so is not robust).

What i feel to suggest you to do is something like this:

1. Delete the notification in the Model
2. Create a Service for this operation, let's call it `NotyfyUsersNewClinicService` (maybe you will find a better name):

```php
<?php

namespace App;
use ...;

class NotyfyUsersNewClinicService{

    public __constructor(){}

    public updateUsers(Clinic& $clinic, Collection& $newUsers){
       $clinic->users->diff($newUsers)->each(function(User $users){
           $user->userData->notification_email = true;
           \Mail::to($user->email)->send(new \App\Mail\ClinicManagerAdded(
                    $user,
                    $clinic));
       });
       $clinic->users()->sync($sync);
    }
}
```

3. then you will only need to use this:

   (new NotyfyUsersNewClinicService())->updateUsers($clinic, $users);

Note: better if you move the email to a job and send it using `queue:work`

Comment: in order to be able to find the deleted, use SoftDelete trait

Answer (score 0):

If someone has a similar problem, I have managed to resolve this by creating the static variable, and fill this variable in the **deleted** event, like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class ClinicUser extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'clinic_user';

    static $ids = [];

    static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleted(function($item){
           self::$ids[] = $item->users_id;
        });

        static::created(function($item){

            if(!\in_array($item->users_id, self::$ids)){
                $user   = \App\User::find($item->users_id);
                $clinic = \App\Models\Clinic::find($item->clinics_id);

                if($user->userData->notification_email == 1)
                    \Mail::to($user->email)->send(new \App\Mail\ClinicManagerAdded(
                        $user,
                        $clinic));

                if($user->userData->notification_app == 1)
                    \App\Notification::create([
                        'title'   => "new message",
                        'body'    => "<p>body</p>",
                        'user_id' => $user->id,
                    ]);
            }


        });
    }
}
```

Comment: and i am pretty sure that this solution won't work, i'm pretty sure that a rebooting of the server (or interruption of service) will cause that variable to reset, and so it will be emptied (and so your server won't be able to check if it is been deleted in the past or not)